# Shape adjustment in excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba

I insert a shape of type rounded rectangular callout at run time and initially its pointer's direction is downward.If i check its value using

```
shp.Adjustments.Item(1)
```

code then it shows its value -0.20833

I want to change its direction to upward.I recorded a macro to adjust that and got this code

```
Selection.ShapeRange.Adjustments.Item(1) = -0.20223
```

But still its direction is downward.
Please help to set its direction to upward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest just rotating the shape 180 degrees on the y axis.  This rotates the shape, but as you note it also rotates the text which may not be desirable.

```
shp.ShapeRange.ThreeD.RotationY = -180
```

If you simply want to adjust the pointer from the callout, this is `Item(2)`.  When I create a shape, it has a value like:

```
shp.Adjustments.Item(2) = 0.625
```

To reverse its location, so that it is on the top of the rectangle, change it to:

```
shp.Adjustments.Item(2) = -0.625
```

Comment: Hi David, In my case it doesn't work as it rotates text direction as well and i dont want that.

Comment: @Mechanic see my revision; change the value for `shp.Adjustments.Item(2)`.